# Removing automounted USB device

Tags: usb, automount

I want a disk connected via usb to automatically mount (so that I don't have to open nautilus and mount the device before launching applications that access some files on the disk). Automounting works (configured with `gnome-disks`), however I now have the problem that I can no longer umount the disk (without sudo). When I plug the disk in it gets automatically mounted, how do I safely unplug the disk again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can add the **user** flag to the mount options stored in /etc/fstab from gnome-disks. Just click on edit mount options.